# Can I use CWM recovery made for KitKat in Lollipop?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, clockworkmod-recovery, flashtool

I was already using CWM on kitkat until I officially updated my Micronax Unite 2 A106 (MT6582) to lollipop. But when I tried to use the same recovery made for kitkat in lollipop, it did not work. Why does that happen? Does that mean I can't use recovery made for kitkat in lollipop?
According to xda wiki "The recovery is completely independent of the Android system". Does it mean that, No matter which version of Android I have, the recovery of any version should work. If recovery is independent of android then why does that recovery not working. I am confused.

Comment: did you re-flash the custom recovery after updating to Lollipop? The update overwrote your recovery most likely. So reflashing should bring back your CWM recovery.

Comment: Yes, I tried falshing that same cwm recovey, but it boots into android instead of recovery. So I had flash again the stock recovery of lollipop.

Comment: Were you able to successfully flash CWM after updating to lollipop? If yes, try rebooting into recovery using adb or perhaps a reboot manager (If you're rooted)

Comment: As I said when I try to boot into recovery, it shows black screen and after some time it boots into android instead of recovery.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past, it could be that Lollipop is preventing the recovery from root access, it is disabled by default.

Go to settings -> developer options -> root access. Enable the option for apps & adb.

If you can't see the developer options go to settings -> about phone. Then tap on the build number section 10 times (it works as a hidden button)

Comment: I have flashed custom recovery from fastboot. So i don't think it has something to do with root access

Comment: *it could be that Lollipop is preventing the recovery from root access:* I doubt that. Recovery usually is a separate system, independent from the "main Android" system. While you can access the entire device from both, they otherwise have not much to do with each other – especially Recovery doesn't care much about settings from the main system, so your "developer options" will be ignored completely by it.

Comment: @lzzy You are right.